# How to run quartz scheduler everyday once at 3 PM

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

I tried below two:

```
CronSchedule("0 15 * * *") 
CronSchedule("0 0 15 ? * MON-SUN")
```

Both triggers the process again after sometime.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "Both triggers the process again after sometime"?

Comment: both the above cron schedule ways restart the job again in sometime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run Job is 3pm everyday. You use expression: 0 0 15 * * ?